# Display objects as property of modules in Corona SDK / Lua? (composer)

Tags: oop, module, lua, coronasdk

I am developing games with the `composer` library of Corona SDK and I am facing a problem with *design patterns*. Let's say I have a bunch of `modules`, that I make globally accessible in `main.lua`. After thinking about how I would make communication between `modules` easy, I came up with the approach to make the generated `display objects` `properties` of the `module`. I first tried the oop approach but then I ended up wrestling through complicated `parameter structures`, that passed the `objects` which made `debugging` a pain.
Is there any problem with this approach, that you can see? Do I need to rethink my approach for the sake of stability?

Thanks for your help!

Greetings, Nils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try use [Custom Events](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/06/26/how-to-use-custom-events-in-corona/) to objects communication. Also read

- [Using custom events to make game objects communicate](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/49803-using-custom-events-to-make-game-objects-communicate/) on Corona forum
- [Creating and Dispatching Custom Events in Corona SDK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7NvOH7eLAI) on YouTube

What is more I recommended you analyse three free and open source games from [Ponywolf](http://ponywolf.com) on Corona [marketplace](https://marketplace.coronalabs.com/vendor/b244ad3e-52d1-48da-9756-ad936eab1ee7). I do it myself :)

Comment: Great! Didn't expect an answer that soon. If it is, what I think it is, then you saved me a LOT of thinking pain! I'll take your advice analysing the games also for the future. Thanks alot!

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for... thanks alot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)